# RO Drain Pipe Connected to Air Gap is leaking

Tags: plumbing

I don't have space on my pipe to install the drain adapter. I have one sink, and that has a garbage disposal unit.

Under the garbage disposal unit, I only have P-Trap without much space on the pipe to put the drain adapter. I was told that one should not install this after P-Trap since it means that odor from the P-Trap gets into the filter.

One of the plumbers told me to install a three-pronged air gap and connect the drain pipe into that air-gap. But, for some reason, the connection is not working out, and it is leaking from there.

I am not sure what can be fixed. Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe include a picture so we can respond better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You might want to take our tour to become familiar with how the site operates. Also, please edit your question to be clearer on what you're trying to do. It sounds as if you might be trying to install a drain line for your dishwasher - but I'm not sure. What is the "drain adapter" you're referring to? Pictures would help.

Comment: What is a **RO drain pipe** ? **Drain adapter** for what ? Please edit your question to provide more details, and photos would be very helpful.

Comment: RO - Reverse Osmosis?

Comment: Can you post photos of the plumbing please?